# Class methods are not performing correct calculations

Tags: java, class, methods

Currently have project for school I am working on, here are the requirements:

> Write a Temperature class  that will hold a temperature in Fahrenheit
>   and provide methods  to get the temperature in Fahrenheit, Celsius,
>   and Kelvin. The class  should have the following field:
>
> - `ftemp`: a double  that holds a Fahrenheit temperature.
>
> The class should have the following methods:
>
> - **`Constructor`**: The constructor  accepts a Fahrenheit temperature (as a double) and stores  it in the ftemp field.
> - **`setFahrenheit`**: The set Fahrenheit method  accepts a Fahrenheit temperature (as a double) and stores  it in the ftemp field.
> - **`getFahrenheit`**: Returns the value  of the ftemp field as a Fahrenheit temperature (no conversion required)
> - **`getCelsius`**: Returns the value  of the ftemp field converted to Celsius. Use the following formula to convert to Celsius: `Celsius = (5/9) * (Fahrenheit - 32)`
> - **`getKelvin`**: Returns the value  of the ftemp field converted to Kelvin. Use the following formula to convert to Kelvin: `Kelvin = ((5/9) * (Fahrenheit - 32)) + 273`
>
> Demonstrate the Temperature class  by writing a separate program tha asks the user for a Fahrenheit temperature. The program should create an instance of the Temperature class, with the value  entered by the user passed to the constructor . The program  should then call the object's methods to display the temperature in the following format (for example, if the temperature in Fahrenheit was -40):
>
> - The temperature in Fahrenheit is -40.0
> - The temperature in Celsius is -40.0
> - The temperature in Kelvin is 233.0

Here is my current code:

## Temperature(Class)

```
public class Temperature {

    private double ftemp;

    public Temperature(double temp)
    {
        ftemp = temp;
    }

    public void setFahrenheit(double t)
    {
        ftemp = t;
    }

    public double getFahrenheit()
    {
        return ftemp;
    }

    public double getCelsius()
    {
        return (5/9) * (ftemp - 32);
    }

    public double getKelvin()
    {
         return ((5/9) * (ftemp - 32)) + 273;

    }

}
```

## MPL1(Main source code)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MPL1 {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        double input;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a Fahrenheit temperature: ");

        input = keyboard.nextDouble();

        Temperature myTemp = new Temperature(input);


        System.out.println("The temperature in Fahrenheit is " + 
                    myTemp.getFahrenheit());
        System.out.println("The temperature in Celsius is " +
                    myTemp.getCelsius());
        System.out.println("The temperature in Kelvin is " +
                            myTemp.getKelvin());

    }
}
```

When executed, it performs almost everything correctly, however, using `getCelsius` and `getKelvin` give me results of `0.0` and `273.0` regardless of what number is entered.

Comment: Instead of writing the same formula twice, you could change `getKelvin()` to return `getCelsius() + 273`. As for your question, it looks like you are entering `32`. Please give example inputs and results.

Answer (score 4):

`5/9` is integer division, and since 9 divides into 5 zero times, `5/9 = 0`. Cast it to a double instead: `((double)5/9)`.

Answer (score 4):

`5/9 == 0` in Java because both `5` and `9` are `int` literals. You need to explicitly use floating point literals:

```
return (5.0/9.0) * (ftemp - 32.0);

return ((5.0/9.0) * (ftemp - 32.0)) + 273.15;
```

See [Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)